# when can i use <tbody> <thead> <tfoot> insteadof the common tr th td?

Tags: html

When can I use `<tbody> <thead> <tfoot>` insteadof the common labels such as `<tr> <th> <td>`? IS the label such as `<tbody> <thead> <tfoot>` better than  `tr th td` and why?

Comment: They are not an alternative, they are an addition to structure the table. Please read the documentation. That is all explained.

Comment: I never said anything like that. Why "not useful at all"? I specifically explained that they are an addition to the structure elements you already know.

Comment: Sounds like you did _not_ take a look into the documentation. May we know _why_ not?

Comment: You've twisted my words. What I mean is THAT I can finish one table by not using them. And the table will be also understood well by  browsers and someone with visual Impairments

Comment: Certainly you can implement a html table without those. That is why I named them as "additional". And I absolutely fail to see where I "twisted your words"! If so, please show me! Instead you removed your own comment. May we ask _why_ again?

Comment: People with visual impairments are certainly among those that can benefit from all additional structure in documents that is possible. So from thaat point of view it certainly is a good idea to use structural elements wherever possible.That is a general statement, nothing specific can be said, since impairments are often of very unique character.

Answer (score 0):

here you will find a [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tbody.asp) .

```html
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Month</th>
     <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
  <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>January</td>
     <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```